# Get alpha-beta plot of Clarke Transform in Python

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, detection, python, fault

For a project I'm working on, I want to use the Clarke Transform to detect faults in a power system. To do this, I already wrote a script in Python which returns the sine wave behavior of the Alpha, Beta and Zero components of the transform for an ABC system given in the form

$$s(t) = A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

Getting the amplitude and phase is easy enough to do from the ABC system. However, when I compute the Clarke transform, my program returns three numpy arrays: one for each component (\$\alpha\$, \$\beta\$, \$0\$). Since they are returned to me in the form of numpy arrays, getting the amplitude and phase of those waves is not so straightforward, since I don't have an equation in the form of

$$s(t) = A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

for these numpy arrays.

The first question I wanted to ask was if someone knows how I can get the amplitude and phase of the Clarke transform only with the numpy arrays I have.

The second and final question I wanted to ask is if someone knows of a way to plot the \$\alpha-\beta\$ plane in Python or MATLAB with the space vector in real time. For example, I would like to plot the \$\alpha-\beta\$ plane for the transform I just got.

Thanks so much for any information you can give me in advance.

Comment: Is this strictly speaking an EE question?

Comment: @Andyaka yeah, Clarke Transform is used in Power Systems in Electrical Engineering for signal analysis.

Comment: Your first question appears to be about numpy arrays and not about the clarke transform. Your second question appears to be how to plot it in python or matlab. Your question does not appear to be about clarke transforms. Just because you mention clarke transforms doesn't make your question inevitably eligible as an EE question. So, please justify why you think it's an EE question and not a software tool question.